# how to merge rows in a table in powerpoint using win32:OLE in perl

Tags: perl, powerpoint

i am able to add a new table on the slide using Win32:OLE in perl...but i am looking into **merge a couple of rows in the table**....can anyone provide any tips on that. 
**OR** it would also help if i could get any help on how to insert data into an existing table on the Slide, i.e. **how to read the table object of the Existing table** in the powerpoint file.

```
my $Slide = $Presentation->Slides->Add({Index=>$value , Layout=>ppLayoutText});
$Slide->{Name} = "Slide1343121";
my $Title = $Slide->Shapes->{Title};
$Title->TextFrame->TextRange->{Text} ="Title";
$Title->TextFrame->TextRange->Font->{Size} = "32";
my $table = $Slide->Shapes->AddTable( "5, 6, 1, 115);`
```

can anyone help me upgrade my code with the functionalities i am looking for..?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never used Perl with PowerPoint but I thinks its just regular COM access.

In VBA you merge cells and change their text like this

```
tableShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Merge table.Cell(1, 2) ' Merge first and second cell
tableShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Text"
```

So I guess in Perl it looks more or less like this, no?

```
$table->Table->Cell(1, 1)->Merge( $table->Table->Cell(1, 2) );
$table->Table->Cell(1, 1)->Shape->TextFrame->TextRange->{Text} = "Text";
```